# I am new to SQL and i have trouble selecting from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table with student details and gpa

```
|clg_id  | sgpa |  sem_type |
-----------------------------
|o170431 | 9.6  |  sem1     |
|o170431 | 9.8  |  sem2     |
|o170440 | 9.2  |  sem1     |
|o170440 | 8.6  |  sem2     |
|o170450 | 8.2  |  sem1     |
|o170450 | 9.1  |  sem2     |
----------------------------
```

I Want my result table after query would be like below

```
|clg_id  | sem1_sgpa |  sem2_sgpa|
---------------------------------
|o170431 |    9.6    |  9.8     |
|o170440 |    9.2    |  8.6     |
|o170450 |    8.2    |  9.1     |
--------------------------------
```

how should i write sql query to get result like above?

Comment: Based on what?  Explain your requirement.  Then show what you have tried, this has been discussed before.  See [ask] and [mcve].  You should complete the tour which explains the basics for using SO.

Comment: If you have a sem3, would you expect an extra column in the results for that?

Comment: yes if there is sem3 then i want an extra colom

Comment: You should search for mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` with `SUM` to get the output.

`CASE` is to filter the specific value from the column `sem_type`.

`SUM` with `GROUP BY` is to sum up all the values and produce a unique result.

```
select
    clg_id,
    sum(case when sem_type = 'sem1' then sgpa end) as sem1_sgpa,
    sum(case when sem_type = 'sem2' then sgpa end) as sem2_sgpa
from
    student_details
group by 
    clg_id;
```

*yes if there is sem3 then I want an extra column*

**Edit:**  It can be achieved by creating a dynamic query using prepared statement.

So basically it will work for `n`number of sem(s) instead of updating the query manually.

```
select 
group_concat(concat("sum(case when sem_type = '",sem_type,"' then ",sgpa," end) as ",sem_type,"_sgpa")) 
into @dynamiccol
from (select sem_type from student_details group by sem_type) t;

set @dynamicquery = concat("select clg_id, ",@dynamiccol," from student_details group by clg_id");

prepare stmt from @dynamicquery;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: how group_concat and case works,can you explain

Comment: Is the above query working?

Comment: yes that query is working perfectly

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned the column datatype i have added `group_concat` or `sum` works well too.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT clg_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sem_type="sem1" THEN sgpa END) AS "sem1",
       SUM(CASE WHEN sem_type="sem2" THEN sgpa END) AS "sem2",
       #for additional sem, if any
       SUM(CASE WHEN sem_type="sem3" THEN sgpa END) AS "sem3",
       SUM(CASE WHEN sem_type="sem4" THEN sgpa END) AS "sem4"
FROM your_table
GROUP BY clg_id;
```

Demo fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oHgnnz1w9n7TdRz5Ak16eY/1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
p1.clg_id as cig_id ,p1.sgpa as sem1_gpa,p2.sgpa as sem2_gpa 
from
(select sgpa,clg_id from student_details where  sem_type='sem1') as p1
inner join
(select sgpa,clg_id from student_details where  sem_type='sem2') as p2  
on p1.clg_id = p2.clg_id ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Why did you apply such code, where is the focus, some results of this query?
I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).